# Pandas: check if count of occurence of each element of a dataframe column is equal to the element occurence count in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Giving two dataframes df1:

```
col1 
-----
1
1
1
2
3
1
1
2
```

and df2:

```
colA | colB
------------
1    | 2
1    | 4
2    | 1
3    | 1
5    | 1
4    | 5
```

I want to return `True` if the count of the occurence of every element `e` in `col1` in `df1` is equal to the count of the occurence of `e` in both `colA` and `colB` in `df2`.

In the example above for `df1` and `df2` it should return `True`.

Explanation:

count of occurence of `1` in `col1` in `df1`= 5 = count of occurence of `1` in `colA` and `colB` in `df2`.

count of occurence of `2` in `col1` = 2 = count of occurence of `2` in `colA` and `colB` in `df2`.

count of occurence of `3` in `col1` = 1 = count of occurence of `3` in `colA` and `colB` in `df2`

Logic:
The idea is to groupby the elements of `col1` in `df1` and count the occurences of each one of it then go search the count of their occurence in `colA` and `colB` in `df2`.

I've tried the following code:

```
def records_check(df1, df2):
    if df1.groupby(['col1']).size() == df2.groupby(['colA', 'colA']).size():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But I've got this:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this especially when dealing with huge data please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on col1 and the [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)ed version of `df2`, then compare the outputs:

```
c1 = df1['col1'].value_counts(sort=False)
c2 = df2.stack().value_counts(sort=False)
# if more columns
# c2 = df2[['colA', 'colB']].stack().value_counts()

out = c1.eq(c2.reindex_like(c1)).all()
```

[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) variant:

```
# get values and counts for each dataset
n1, c1 = np.unique(df1['col1'], return_counts=True)
n2, c2 = np.unique(df2[['colA', 'colB']].to_numpy().ravel(), return_counts=True)

# compare the counts for existing values in `df1['col1']`
np.array_equal(c1, c2[np.isin(n2, n1)])
```

Output: `True`

Comment: Wow! it works like magic! thanks a lot.
Can you please explain when is preferred to use the first code and when to use the second code?

Comment: @NewUser I expected the numpy variant to be faster. A [quick test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bcen.png) on up to 16M rows with numbers between 0 and 200 shows that numpy is faster for less than ~50K rows, then pandas is faster.

Comment: Actually you can even use `sort=False` in the pandas version, which should be a few percent faster.

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks for your help!!